# Creating a Minesweepers game in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, minesweeper

I'm new in smalltalk language and my teacher asked me to make a minesweeper game to exhibit later at my college class, so I need any kind of help here. All material that I found is from before 2011 and does not match with squeak 5.0(current version).But I recently found a minesweepers project in smalltalk language, but does not works in newer versions of squeak( and I don't even know how to run in the old ones), if someone can explain how it works would be great.

http://www.mjfleming.net/Resume/Smalltalk/Minesweeper/minesweeper.html

Comment: http://squeak.org/documentation/ has a lot of documentation; when you work through these, you'll find that most still apply. The Link you gave is an MVC based game; you need to open an MVC Project (Projects menu) to use it. It works somehow, but you might want to start from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [Laser Game tutorial](http://squeak.preeminent.org/tut2007/html/), that explains how to make a game model and the GUI for it using Morphic

Answer (score 1):

[Squeak by Example (link)](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00441576/file/SBE.pdf) and [Pharo by Example (link)](http://pdxscholar.library.pdx.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1110&context=compsci_fac) both have a worked example of a cell-clicking game, that could be readily adapted to use for MineSweeper.